# Redirecting Site with ReWrite, Need Exceptions for Addon Domains?

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm temporarily redirecting all my website's traffic to an entirely different site with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.othersite.net/ [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

How do I make exceptions for two addon domains I have?  The sites are in their own top-level directories, and the addon domain names are mapped to sub-domains of my domain name.